# Customer specific discount to specific products without using any shopify app?

Tags: shopify, netsuite

I am required to cover the following scenarios without using any 3rd party app to avoid syncing information from NetSuite.

1. Customer group based discount(Equivalent %age of discount will apply
   to the whole cart).

   For e.g:

   - Product 1: $100, Product 2: $200
   - Customer Group A | Discount Percentage: 5%
   - Customer Group B | Discount Percentage: 10%
   - Group A: Product 1: $95, Product 2: $190
   - Group B: Product 1: $90, Product 2: $180.
2. Customer specific discount to specific products.

   For e.g:

   - Product 1: $100, Product 2: $200
   - For Customer A, product 1 should be $80 and Product 2 should be $195
   - For Customer B, product 1 should be $95 and Product 2 should be $185

Can you please explain in brief, how we can alter the product price.
If your answer is the Shopify scripts then I have the following questions:

- Where should we store the percentage of customer group discount?
- Will metafields of products/customer can be accessible in the Shopify script?

Looking forward to reply.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a script to handle this in Plus, your script is a story. You can store a percentage as a variable, and it sticks around for every checkout. As for metafields, it seems doubtful but in your script you can check in 2 seconds whether you'd have access or not. Just try accessing one.